# PHP SOAP Fault does not give line number?

Tags: php, soap

I have a syntax error in my PHP script, which would be simple to fix if PHP gave me the line number where the error occurred.

But all I get back from PHP's Soap Server class is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My Server PHP code is:

```
$server = new SoapServer(__APP_PATH_VAR."WSDL/MYWSDL.wsdl");
$server->setClass('MY_SOAP_CLASS',$this->Core);
$server->handle();
```

The error is being automatically generated- I don't have any code to produce this message.

How do I make PHP include the line number where the error occurred in the response?

Comment: Ah, SOAP. Don'tcha just LOVE it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the start of your document to debug:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);  ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

Comment: So what is the contents of your args ?

Comment: Actually, just for s&g's remove the args from the call and try it again..  See if the error comes up.. If it does then its in your class.. If that is the case, simply loading the class directly should give you the line number of the error

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking? What args?

Comment: Sorry.. Was out of town for a week..    what is the contents of $this->Core ?